# If bitwise quadratic time is considered unfeasible, then what really is feasible for large numbers?

Tags: asymptotics, exponential-function, factoring, cryptography

The naive algorithm for factoring a semi-prime $n$ runs $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n})$. Let's consider the bit-wise complexity of division to be $\mathcal{O}(b^2)$. That means the bitwise complexity of naive factoring is $\mathcal{O}(b^2\sqrt{n}) \in \mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n}^2\sqrt{n}) = \mathcal{O}(n^{1.5})$.

At first glance, this still seems pretty good. I understand that when $n$ is on the order of $2^{1000}$, even this under-quadratic complexity becomes unfeasible but then no matter what the runtime, you can always find an unfeasible $n$, e.g., if the runtime was $\mathcal{O}(\log_2(n))$, we could let $n = 2^{2^{1000}}$ and just like that even log time becomes unfeasible.

Could someone explain why then we often hear that factoring is an "exponentially" hard problem? Is that true? I mean, obviously it has been hard and things like RSA depend on it but is it really exponential? Or, is the matter really of picking the big enough number $n$?

If it is exponential how can I drive that in terms of big-Oh?

**Edit:** I understand that $f(b)=2^b$ is exponential thus when we increase the bits, $n=2^b$ grows exponentially. However, I am finding it hard to connect the dots between value versus length based complexity analysis. When we say factoring is $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n})$ we have assumed that the time complexity of division is constant therefore,

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\sqrt{n}}\mathcal{O}(1) = \mathcal{O}(1)_1 + \mathcal{O}(1)_2 + ... + \mathcal{O}(1)_{\sqrt{n}} = \mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n}).
$$

Now I understand if we let go of the assumption that division is constant and plug the true complexity in the above set-up, we should get an exponential runtime. Say we take the [Schoolbook long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations) then for "two b-digit numbers", division is $\mathcal{O}(b^2)$

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\sqrt{n}}\mathcal{O}(b^2) = \mathcal{O}(b^2)_1 + \mathcal{O}(b^2)_2 + ... + \mathcal{O}(b^2)_{\sqrt{n}} = \mathcal{O}(b^2\sqrt{n}).
$$

Since $\mathcal{O}(\log_2(n)) = \mathcal{O}(b) \in \mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n})$, we can write this as $\mathcal{O}(n\sqrt{n}) = \mathcal{O}({n^{1.5}})$.

The answers say that since $n=2^b$, $\mathcal{O}(2^{1.5b})$ is exponential and when I think about it like that, it makes sense. However, the way we write $n$ in big-Oh shouldn't really matter because we have already accounted for the non-constant division cost so,

$$
n=2^b \Rightarrow \mathcal{O}(n^{1.5}) = \mathcal{O}(2^{1.5b})
$$

This feels somewhat rigging because if you give someone $g(x)=x$ and they say oh but I'll input $2^b, 2^{b+1}, 2^{b+3}, ...$ so your function $g$ is exponential! Well, what makes the function exponential is not really the growth of the function but the input given to function is being grown exponentially!

Comment: Isn't the point that a $b$-bit number is of order $2^b$? To use the method you suggest requires on the order of $\sqrt{2^b}$ divisions.

Comment: If I remember correctly, $b$ is the number of bits in $2^b$ and $\mathcal{O}(b^2)$ since $\lg{2^b}=b$. Yes, it will be $\sqrt{2^b}$ but then my point was that the difficulty here comes from the hugeness of $2^b$ and the runtime can be whatever, we can find an $n$ such that the calculation is difficult. See the $\log_2(2^{2^{b}})$ example.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. If factorizing requires $\sqrt{2^b}$ trial divisions and each division takes $b^2$ machine steps, then factorizing requires $b^2\cdot\sqrt{2^b}$ machine steps. This is (more than) exponential in $b$, that is, in the number of digits it takes to represent the number you are factorizing. So a number close to 1000 (four digits) takes about 30 trial divisions; a number close to 1,000,000 (seven digits) needs 1000 trial divisions; a number close to $10^{100}$ (101 digits) needs 100,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 trial divisions.

Comment: Several mistakes in the edit: it should be $\mathcal{O}\left(\sqrt{n}b^2\right)$, not $\mathcal{O}\left(\sqrt{nb^2}\right)$. If $n\gg b=\lg n$, it is not that case that $\mathcal{b}=\mathcal{n}$, and therefore one cannot write $\mathcal{O}\left(\sqrt{nb^2}\right)=\mathcal{O}\left(n^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)$. Furthermore, none of the answers said anything about the calculation being $\mathcal{O}\left(2^{\frac{3b}{2}}\right)$. Finally, if $g(x)=x$ and $h(b)=2^b$ then $g$ is linear in $x$ and $g\circ h$ is...

Comment: ... exponential in $b$. If you care about how long the calculation takes in terms of the number of digits in the input, then $b^2\cdot\sqrt{2^b}$ is the quantity you're interested in.

Comment: I fixed the $\sqrt{nb^2} \neq b^2\sqrt{n}$ blunder. But still, since $n=2^b$ and $\mathcal{O}(\log_2(n)) = \mathcal{O}(b) \in \mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n})$, we can write this as $\mathcal{O}(n\sqrt{n}) = \mathcal{O}({n^{1.5}}) = \mathcal{O}({2^{1.5b}})$. Is there still something wrong with this big-Oh estimate?

Comment: It's fine: $\mathcal{O}(\log_2 n)\subset\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n})$. You could of course equally well write $\mathcal{O}(\log_2 n)\subset\mathcal{O}(n^{0.0000001})$ and conclude that your trial-division algorithm is $\mathcal{O}(n^{0.5000001})$. Or you could just say that your algorithm is $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n}(\log_2 n)^2)$. It doesn't much matter since they're all exponential in the number of digits of $n$. A 1000-digit number is *a lot* harder to factorize than a 10-digit number.

Comment: I should add that I misspoke when I wrote that nobody say anything about the calculation being $\mathcal{O}\left(2^\frac{3b}{2}\right)$ as this did appear in comments as a (very crude) upper bound. Not sure why one would want to use a crude bound when one could easily use a much tighter one. But the tighter one is still exponential, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could someone explain why then we often hear that factoring is an "exponentially" hard problem?

Trial division is an exponential-time algorithm because runtime is measured as a function of the *length* of the input and not the *value* of the input bit-string. Because of this, you need $\mathcal O(2^{b/2})$ divisions to factor with trial division on a semi-prime of length $b$ bit. Clearly, this is an exponential-time algorithm. If you're still skeptical, compare this runtime to that of regular multiplication which runs in time $\mathcal O(b^2)$.

> I mean, obviously it has been hard and things like RSA depend on it but is it really exponential?

*Technically*, no, because you have sub-exponential time factoring algorithms like the [General Number Field Sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve). However, they are still sufficiently slow that a moderate increase in keysize keeps the required effort to be infeasibly high.

> if the runtime was $\mathcal O(\log_2(n))$, we could let $n=2^{2^{1000}}$

Yes, that would work, but then you'd run into the situation where you need so absurdly large numbers that factoring the semiprime is faster than actually encrypting or decrypting data. Even if you picked a worse algorithm like $\mathcal O(\log_2^5(n))$, you still get into a situation where you need to pick keys that are like 1GB which is ... rather unpractical for most applications. In fact, [quantum computers can factor in this kind of time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor_algorithm) and pqRSA ([paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/351), [slides](https://cr.yp.to/talks/2018.04.11-2/slides-djb-20180411-2-pqrsa-16x9.pdf)) has done the math how large keys would need to be to offer reasonable security and they did arrive at about 1GB of key data.

Comment: You said it yourself, we take the *length* of the input and not the *value*. The length of the value $2^b$ is $\lg{2^b}=b$ then why are you writing the complexity as $\mathcal{O}(2^{\frac{b}{2}})$, instead of $\mathcal{O}(b^{\frac{1}{2}})$?

Comment: The usual division algorithm runs as fast as the multiplication one so they are both $\mathcal{O}(b^2)$, I don't see how you answered my question that if the complexity due to value is $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n})$ where $\sqrt{n}$ is the number of divisions then the compexity due to length is $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{nb^2}) \in \mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n^3}) = \mathcal{O}(n^{1.5})$ where $n >> b$.

Comment: @scribe Trial division has runtime that depends on the value and the value of a $b$-bit integer is on the order of $2^b$ and not $b$, so $\mathcal O(2^{b/2})$ is the correct one. As for the runtime, yes, $\mathcal O(n^{1.5})$ is a valid upper bound for the runtime of trial division. However, this $n$ is the _value_ of the integer and not its length, if you would convert it to length-oriented notation it would be $\mathcal O(2^{3b/2})$ for $b=\log_2 n$.

Comment: Okay, I think I get what makes me uncomfortable here. Do you mind taking a look at my edit?

Comment: @scribe SO is not working in this way. You can ask new questions or ask the answerer before editing the question. The better action is to rollback the edits, and ask a new good question with what you have learned.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind.